# Generate Access Token to call another Api in Identity Server Mvc Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4, access-token

In our work, we've got multiple apis and we use Identity Server 4 as the authentication provider.  Whenever a FE or BE app needs to call the Api, we just use the AccessToken to call Apis.  The Apis authenticate it back to Identity server to validate the token.  It's all working fine for many years.

Now, we've got the new requirement.  We need to host a page (Eg. User Profile or some additional steps in User Registration) in Identity Server to do some actions.  And part of these actions need to call one of the above Apis.

The issue is that, we do not have AccessToken for the user's login.  The following line always return null in Identity Server.

```
    await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
```

So, I don't know how to generate the token in current login user context.

Identity Server never generates a user token if there is no authorize request.  Just logging into Identity Server doesn't generate a token.

Could you please help me how we can generate the user's access token?  Or is there a flaw in design?  Must we host these new pages in separate web app (not in Identity Server)?

[image]